# Error with relative layout. "is not a sibling"

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two Textviews in a RelativeLayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   (*) android:layout_above="@+id/message"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/message"
     android:layout_width="302dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"/>
</ScrollView>
```

I want the Textview id'd "message" to be scrollable. So I added it within a ScrollView but where I have put a star (android:layout_above) I am getting the error: @+id/message is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to remove **"+"** from

This

`android:layout_above="@+id/message"`

To

```
android:layout_above="@id/message"
```

And use TextView's scrolling method rather than scrollview

```
<TextView
 android:scrollbars="vertical" // Add this to your TextView in .xml file
 android:maxLines="ANY_INTEGER" // also add the maximum line 
 android:id="@+id/message"
 android:layout_width="302dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_above="@id/editText1"/>
```

Then after in your .java file add following methods for your textview above.

```
TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
message.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Its works with "+" as well but what you have written is correct. We should use a + only when giving the id, not while using it.

Answer (score 3):

It is giving this error because your TextView's parent is not relative layout,it's ScrollView. Instead give an id to your ScrollView and then use:

```
 android:layout_above="ScrollView id here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your ScrollView and align relative to the ScrollView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   (*) android:layout_above="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
     android:id="@+id/scroll">
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/message"
     android:layout_width="302dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your TextView id to the ScrollView so that `above` refers to a sibling.

```
 <RelativeLayout> <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" (*)   
 android:layout_above="@+id/message"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true " />       
 <ScrollView   
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/message
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
 android:layout_weight="1"> <TextView  
 android:id="@+id/message"    
 android:layout_width="302dp"/> 
 </ScrollView>`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use scrollview to make your TextView Scrollable. Rather use scrolling movement method like this way.**

```
TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
message.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```